# Identify if an element is a fork or a join in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have an activity diagram in which a fork/join element is used. I have to figure out whether the element is used as a fork or a join using the db or its API. Is there any way to find this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same object in EA, so at the object itself you can't see if it's a join or a fork.

So you need to figure out another way of knowing if it's used as a join or as a fork.

The difference is in the linked control flows

- Fork: One incoming flow, multiple outgoing flows

[image]

- Join: Multiple incoming flows, one outgoing flow

[image]

I think I would us an SQL query to figure out if my object is used as a Fork or as a Join

Query to check for Fork

```
select o.Object_ID from t_object o
where o.ea_guid = '{3E91C35F-A454-4282-944C-F07BD0D86F91}'
and 1 = --only one incoming flow
  (select count(*) from t_connector c
  where c.End_Object_ID = o.Object_ID
  and c.Connector_Type = 'ControlFlow') 
and  1 < --more than one outgoing flow
  (select count(*) from t_connector c
  where c.Start_Object_ID = o.Object_ID
  and c.Connector_Type = 'ControlFlow')
```

Query to check for Join

```
select o.Object_ID from t_object o
where o.ea_guid = '{0CD27AF4-873C-4c64-A230-B40CE57E7F83}'
and 1 < --more than one incoming flow
  (select count(*) from t_connector c
  where c.End_Object_ID = o.Object_ID
  and c.Connector_Type = 'ControlFlow') 
and  1 = --exactly one outgoing flow
  (select count(*) from t_connector c
  where c.Start_Object_ID = o.Object_ID
  and c.Connector_Type = 'ControlFlow')
```

Replace the GUID in the query with the GUID of the suspected Fork/Join
You can use `EA.Repository.SQLQuery()` to execute these queries.

Answer (score 2):

Only by looking at the number of ingoing anf outgoing connectors. A `Fork` has exactly one incoming edge and a `Join` exactly one outgoing edge.

Unlikely, but possible: if there's a note attached you need to check (best always) whether the connectors are of type object and/or control flow.

Comment: Looks like we agree on the solution :)

Comment: @GeertBellekens My answer was just faster to edit xD